# SMSMSE Quarantine problems

Tags: symantec, windows-sbs

Does anyone know what happens to quarantined messages that are sent after the quarantine limit has been met? Our limit is set to 1000 but that was met 3 hours ago and all messages are currently being quarantined due to a corrupt definition update. Does this mean that all messages since the limit was met have been lost...?

Many thanks

Comment: Also, does anybody know if there would be a danger in releasing a large number of emails from the quarantine at the same time. They'be all been re-checked and are free of malicious content, I'm just worried about flooding the server with releasing an abnormally large amount simultaneously. Is there anyone with experience of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default setting is that messages will be purged to make room for the new ones(FIFO). I have released large numbers in the past without issue.  Naturally, the mail server receiving the messages may be loaded down for a short period depending on capability.